# react-native run-android got stuck with a white-display on android-studio simulator written "Loading from 10.0.2.2.8081"

Tags: android, react-native

I am a newbie in react-native.I followed the official documentation of react-native to install it on linux-ubuntu.
I followed all the steps.Everthing is running fine except of this problem.
react-native run-android command is running successfully , but got stuck 
with a white background with green strip on the top . The green color strip on the top of emulator is written as " loding from  10.0.2.2.8081"
I am stuck on this problem ,everthing else is running fine ,but the android simulator is stuck on it

### These are my logs on terminal after running  react-native run-android

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && 
./gradlew app:installDebug)...
```

```
10:57:00 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
10:57:00 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:57:00 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_XL_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
10:57:00 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
10:57:00 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
10:57:00 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /home/babita/AwesomeProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-rw-r--
10:57:00 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
10:57:01 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:57:01 V/ddms: execute: returning
10:57:01 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
10:57:01 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:57:01 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Running /home/babita/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on emulator-5554 (/home/babita/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: wait and let it load for minutes.. first time loading is slow..

Comment: I have waited for several minutes ,more than half an hour that's why I have posted the question

Comment: Have you checked your navigator file?

Comment: have you tried running in physical device?

Comment: Try running on physical device..

Comment: I have also tried in the physical device, the error is the same in the physical device also.

Comment: are you using react-native-navigation in your project?

Comment: No its a plain project, am running my first react-native app after following the getting started page of react-native official doc.Am facing several issues - sometimes the cli  is terminated after build successfull , sometimes  the changes in the app.js file is not getting reflected on the simulator

Comment: do you get any error like unable to load from index.android.bundle error?

Comment: yes , sometimes

Comment: okay so I got what your problem is.. check out my answer to your question below and follow what I post in that answer. I am posting the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long discussion with you, I have finally figured out what the problem.
The problem is that you are getting the error

> unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle

and you simply dismiss that error while nothing has been loading for the app from the bundle to display. So that is why you are getting a white screen every time.

Follow these steps in Terminal (since you are using Linux). Windows users follow these steps in CMD

1) Go to your project root directory in Terminal(or CMD)

2) Run this command `mkdir android\app\src\main\assets`

3) After this command run this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

4) then run `react-native run-android` command

***Optional steps***

After step 3 you can follow these steps too:

3.1) `cd android`

3.2) `gradlew clean`

3.3) `cd..`

3.4) `react-native run-android`

Comment: I can't thank you enough, thank you so much for investing so much time in this problem.  I spend my whole day solving this problem, finally got the solution from you. Again thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers!! Happy Learning React Native!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Bring up the react-native developer menu (something that looks like the first image below). I assume that you know how to do that.
- Click on `dev settings`, then click on 'Debug server host & port for device' - see second image below) and type `localhost:8081`
- Try to reload. If it doesn't work, terminate the app and start it again
- If it didn't work try to type the following instead: `localhost:8081/debugger-ui`

[image: dev settings]

[image: Debug server host & port for device]

Comment: There are many options inside Dev settings ,inside dev settings in which option I have to write localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

I had a clean build but still it was stuck at *LOADING* screen. I restarted my machine and it worked.