# app directly crashing rather than displaying red alert

Tags: react-native

Currently I have implemented reactnative to existing native app but its directly crashing when i start it from android studio. windows doesnt turns red as usual.

```
 Process: com.., PID: 15608
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
```

Comment: try running "react-native run-android" in you project main directory (one level above android folder)

Comment: error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Comment: this is not react native project, its native project so thereis app/android...., iam runing it from studio and crashed directly on the log no red screen errors

Comment: @xubilulive It is indeed a react native project running it from android studio doesnt mean that it is a native project

Comment: i have solved the issue wth this. ->

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is that a react native project creates a bundle to load the script for the app which you have not created it so your android app is loading nothing when running the `react-native run-android` command.

Do this in your project root directory:

1- Run this command `mkdir android\app\src\main\assets`

2- After this command, run this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Step 2 command execution might take time (have patience)

3- then run `react-native run-android command`

More info at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438279/react-native-run-android-got-stuck-with-a-white-display-on-android-studio-simula/55442773#55442773) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)